# Apache Beam - Python - Read file

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm runnign a apache beam pipeline in google cloud (through google dataflow). In my python code, I'm trying to read a json file that sits next to my python code.

However, the  json file does not seem to get sent. I tried to log onto the docker instance, but my json file is nowhere to be found.

I know in Java, one could use the `filesToStage` option, but I cannot find the equivalent in python.

What am I missing ?

Comment: I am not sure that the Python SDK has this knob. Have you considered simply staging your file using `gsutil cp` or a similar command?

Comment: That's what we're doing for now but it would have been convenient ans consistent to have the same options as the Java runtime

Comment: You are right about that. I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4442 to track this fix.